# Mongodb nested $grouping and $sum?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm new to MongoDB, so forgive me if I missed something in docs. My collection is like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57553e7015e4117a4343c18c"),
"BuyingPrice" : 55.5,
"Quantity" : NumberLong(1),,
"Brand" : "Ranamina",
"Amount" : 79.99,
"Profit" : 24.49,
"ProductId" : NumberLong(55319),}
```

After calculate total amount for every brands, I want to see how many products in every brand.

I want to see results

```
{"Quantity": 1982,
 "Amount": 155,
 "Number_of_product" :12,
 "_id":{"Brand": "Ranamina"}
}
```

This is my code:

```
collection_test.aggregate([
        {
            '$group': {
                '_id': {
                    'Brand': '$Brand',
                },
                'Amount': {'$sum': '$Amount'},
                'product': {'$addToSet': '$ProductId'},
                'Amount_sum': {'$addToSet': '$Amount'},
            },
        },
        {'$group': {
            '_id': {'Brand': '$_id.Brand', 'ProductId': '$product'},
        }
        },
        {
            '$project': {'count': {'$size': '$_id.ProductId'}, 
            'Groups': '$_id.Groups', '_id': 0, 'Amount_sum':1,
                         }}
    ])
```

I used groups in group method however I couldnt access total amount and total profit. Is there the way to access these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?:

```
collection_test.aggregate([
{
    '$group': {
        '_id': {
            'Brand': '$Brand',
        },
        'Amount': {'$sum': '$Amount'},
        'Quantity': {'$sum': '$Quantity'},
        'product': {'$addToSet': '$ProductId'},
    },
},
{
    '$project': {
        'Quantity': True,
        'Amount': True,
        'Number_of_product': {'$size': '$product'}
    }
}])
```

You definitely don't need two "$group" stages.